# How to find out BIGINT time type?

Tags: mysql, sql

In table I have BIGINT row "last_seen" with values like: `1348038297245` or `1348037202941` but its not an UNIX time. Than what?

Comment: what? it's hard to understand your question.

Comment: What part is ununderstable for you?

Comment: what do you want to do with this number `1348038297245`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are timestamps, but stored in miliseconds instead of just seconds. just divide them by 1000 to get seconds again.

1348038297245ms = 1348038297.245s = 2012-09-19 07:04:57 ([online converter](http://www.gaijin.at/olsutc.php))

Comment: This converter makes date `Tue, 04 Sep 2012 07:18:11 GMT` to `1346743091` but my DB timestamps have more digits like `1343477229116` :/

Comment: as already said: your timestamps are in ms while unix timestamps usually are displayed in seconds. you have to divide by 1000 before converting to a date.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an unix timestamp in ms.

Convert it here : http://www.epochconverter.com/